# AngularJS: HTTP response is empty in startup init() function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, response, startup

I am using AngularJs for my WebUi (html). To determine the logged in user **I am calling a https rest-web-service request at startup time of my HTML page. But the http "response" data are empty.** *(The calling rest web service is running fine in a seperate browser or when it is called in a ng-click event.)*

**So my question is: How can I call a http request at startup time with filled up response data?**

HTML page - calls my javascript function "init()":

```
<body ng-app="MY-APP" ng-controller="webui" ng-init="init()">
```

AngularJs - function init():

```
var app = angular.module('MY-APP', []);
app.controller('webui', function($scope,$http,$log,$window) {

   $scope.init = function() {
       $scope.UserId = $scope.getUserId();
   }

   $scope.getUserId = function() {
       $http.get( $scope.my-app-url + '/user/id' ).then(function (response) {
                 $scope.UserId = response.data.USERID;
                 return $scope.UserId;
             });          
       }
}
```

Comment: I have created a sample fiddle like above..It works fine (http://jsfiddle.net/o6cbk5f9/). Need more info to understand the issue.

Comment: Hi, thank you for this little, nice and useful example. I tried to reach out my URL with the hard coded address instead of using a variable and it worked. Therefore I have an issue with using variables defined thru a function in the same scope. I will address it in my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

all you have is to call your function

```
var app = angular.module('MY-APP', []);
app.controller('webui', function($scope,$http,$log,$window) {

   $scope.UserId=null;

   var getUserId = function() {
       $http.get( $scope.my-app-url + '/user/id' ).then(function (response) {
                 $scope.UserId = response.data.USERID;

             });          
       }

//call your function
getUserId();

}
```

Comment: Calling the function was not the issue. I have some issues of the visibility of the variables in different contexts or with the declaration of the variables. I am looking for a possibility to use defined variables across the functions. It seems I am not quite familiar with declaring variables in JavaScript yet.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not with calling a http request in the startup function. The issue is with determine variables using a functions.

Let me explain in a simple example. Within my function init() I have hardcoded variable definitions like *$scope.io = "csv"* which is working fine - these variables can be used in the same function without issues. But the variable *$scope.my-app-url* which is determined by the function *$scope.getMy-App-Url()* cannot be used in the following function *$scope.getUserId()* to determine the variable *$scope.UserId*, because this variable is "undefined" in that function.

**So, how to declare or define the variable *$scope.my-app-url* to use it in the following function *$scope.getUserId()*?**

```
$scope.init = function() {
    $scope.io = "csv";

    $scope.my-app-url = $scope.getMy-App-Url();

    $scope.UserId = $scope.getUserId();
}

$scope.getMy-App-Url = function() {
    $http.get('my-app-url.json').then(function (response) {
        $scope.my-app-url = response.data.MYAPPURL;
        return $scope.my-app-url;
    });
}

$scope.getUserId = function() {
    $http.get( $scope.my-app-url + '/user/id' ).then(function (response) {
        $scope.UserId = response.data.USERID;
        return $scope.UserId;
    });     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a promise that depends on another promise I would re-write it so that "$scope.my-app-url" is not undefined.

```
$scope.getUserId = function() {
    $http.get('my-app-url.json').then(function (response) {
        $scope.my-app-url = response.data.MYAPPURL;
        $http.get( $scope.my-app-url + '/user/id' ).then(function (response) {
          $scope.UserId = response.data.USERID;
          return $scope.UserId;
        });  
    });
}
```

I couldn't put this in a comment as it wouldn't format properly.

Comment: It feels like a workaround, but your solution works! Thank you very much.

But I am still interested in how to declare a variable correctly in JavaScript...

Comment: @MrStone I think your question isn't so much how to declare a variable in JS but a variable in AngularJs. In the version you're using there are two ways: there are local variables AKA var myVariable = "data" and $scope.myVariable = "data". The first is available inside your controller and can't be accessed in the HTML. The second is available both inside your controller and the HTML. If you want something available throughout your app you can use $rootScope. It's not considered good practice to use this and should be only used for config variables needed in every controller.